# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'firebase.initializeApp(config)')

Tags: react-native

I m trying to fire base connectivity with react native

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

componentWillMount(){
        var config = {
         apiKey: "API_KEY",
         authDomain: "*******-****.firebaseapp.com",
         databaseURL: "https://*******-****.firebaseio.com",
         projectId: "*******-****",
         storageBucket: "*******-*****.appspot.com",
         messagingSenderId: "************",

    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    console.log(firebase);
  }
```

How do I solve this error?

Error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'firebase.initializeApp(config)')

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import it like

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
```

or

```
import firebase from ‘firebase’;
```